# Instance of class as key in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, instance

I have this class:

```
 public class Offer {

        private Integer id;
        private String description;
        private Double price;
        private String currency;
        private Date timeExpired;

        public Offer(Integer id, String description, Double price, String currency, Date timeExpired){

            this.id = id;
            this.description = description;
            this.price = price;
            this.currency = currency;
            this.timeExpired = timeExpired;
        }
}
```

I want to create a hashmap with key that refers to id of the class `Offer` and value as `Offer`.

```
HashMap<id of Offer(?),Offer> repo = new HashMap<id of Offer(?),Offer>();
```

How can I do that?

How assign each `Offer` id as key and the `Offer` objects as values on Hashmap repo?
I mean method repo.put(?)

Comment: What's wrong with `HashMap<Integer, Offer>`?

Comment: `HashMap<Integer, Offer>`

Comment: `repo.put(offer.getId(), offer)`

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the id is an `Integer` your need a `HashMap<Integer, Offer>`:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    HashMap<Integer, Offer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Offer>();

    // First way
    map.put(1038, new Offer(1038, "foo", 10.20, "bar", new Date()));

    // Second way
    Offer o1 = new Offer(1038, "foo", 10.20, "bar", new Date());
    map.put(o1.getId(), o1);

}
```

---

Tips :

- use `int` and `double` rather than `Integer` or `Double` if you don't really need the objects ([`int vs Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623682/using-int-vs-integer#answers))
- use `LocalDate` instead of `Date` it's the latest version, and easier to use

Comment: Do you think op has a reason to use Integer for their id because they are going to use it as a key in a hashmap?

Comment: @matt: I am going to create a RESTful, I think I need Integer for that, because the compiler complains without it.

Comment: @matt With rest app don't know, but you can add int element in a Map<Integer, ..> or List<Integer> ;)

Comment: @azro when you "add an int" element, it is getting autoboxed to an Integer. depending on how often you are doing it, it can help to stick to Integer. Although it sounds like OP needs to use Integer for other reasons.