# Why do I get class cast exception for int.class cast

Tags: java, generics

In below program I fail to understand why there is `ClassCastException` for cast from `int.class`

**Update:**
I should specify I know what primitive types are. `What I don't understand is why int.class is provided with broken implementation?`

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(DataType.INT.getValue(Integer.class));
    System.out.println(DataType.INT.getValue(int.class));//Class cast exception here
}

enum DataType {
    INT {
        @Override
        public <T> T getValue(Class<T> toClass) {
            return toClass.cast(1000);//ClassCastException here for int.class
        }
    };
    public abstract <T> T getValue(Class<T> toClass);

}
```

Comment: enum `INT<T>` is not allowed in java so I am trying to do it other way. But as you can see it is error prone if some once passes `int.class` it will raise an `ClassCastException`. And compiler does restrict `INT<int>` but this way it does not.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after going through some links, and trying out some code, I found out that: -

- `int.class` == `Integer.TYPE` == int
- `int.class` != `Integer.class`

So, the value of `int.class` is Class object representing the type `int`.

So, when you invoke your `DataType.INT` with `int.class`, the `toClass` containts `int`, on which you cannot invoke `cast`. May be because it does not extend from `Object` class. Because, `cast` method internally uses `isinstance` to check whether the invoking type is an `Object` type or not.

```
public T cast(Object obj) {
if (obj != null && !isInstance(obj))
    throw new ClassCastException();
return (T) obj;
}
```

So, if the type that invokes `cast` is not an instance of `Object`, which of course `primitive` types are not, it will return `false`, and hence a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Found the cause added it as answer.

Comment: @AmitD.. Yeah I just got that link also. But as you posted it. So no need to post. :)

Comment: I think little room for improvement in your last statement. It's a fact that all the classes in Java extend `Object`. There is no instanceof check against `Object`.

Comment: "So, the value of int.class is int." This doesn't make any sense at all. `int` is a type, not a value. The value of `int.class` is a `Class` object that represents the type `int`.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `cast()` operation of `Class` uses [isInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) `method which returns false for primitive classes`.

> If this Class object represents a primitive type, this method returns false.

Code for `cast()` method is below

```
public T cast(Object obj) {
if (obj != null && !isInstance(obj))//It fails here since isInstance returns false
    throw new ClassCastException();
return (T) obj;
```

Comment: And the autoboxing causes obj to be an instance of `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer` is a class wrapper for `int` values, while `int` is a primitive type, not a class. Don't confuse between primitive types and classes, for example, in code when you must use classes:

```
List<int> lstInteger; //won't compile!
List<Integer> lstInteger; //compiles fine
```

More info:

- [Java: int versus Integer](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/08/java-int-versus-integer.html)
- [Java: int or integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/423704/1065197)

---

Think of `int` type as a primitive C/C++ int type. Knowing this, the int is not a class, thus not having any attributes, any methods, just holding a integer value. On the other hand, `java.lang.Integer` is a class wrapper for `int` primitive type. This is in order to use the `int` in cases where only object instances could be used. A good example of this is the generic system in Java that works only for classes (as proposed in your code example).

For deeper info in this, you can read from the Oracle Java Tutorial: [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: Both of these links does not specify that `cast` should fail ?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. If you see careful, he is the OP

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the fact that `int.class` is not same as `Integer.class`.

**Update**

---

We can look at the cast method, it parameter is an `Object` so it's obvious that 1000 get autoboxed, thus the actual argument to the method is an instance of `Integer`:

```
public T cast(Object obj) {
if (obj != null && !isInstance(obj))
    throw new ClassCastException();
return (T) obj;
}
```

Comment: I know that but why `cast` operation fails as finally its a class object ?

Comment: There's no such class int, it's a primitive type.

Comment: @AmitD: Cause they are not same class and they don't share parent-child relationship.

Comment: It looks like you're confusing Java with other OOP languages. In Java, `int` is just a primitive type, not a class. `int.anyMethod` will be a compiler error.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: You should give it a try on your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

A class cast exception is thrown by Java when you try to cast an Object of one data type to another. Here int is not an Object, it's a primitive which gets instantiated by some native code at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what happening:

When you call `return toClass.cast(1000);`, the literal `1000` is getting promoted to `Integer`. Promotion rules are mentioned here : [**Java Language Specification**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.1).

Now when, `cast` method is called on `intClass`, its checks if argument(1000) is of same instance i.e. `int.class` and it fails because its not.

On the other hand, when you cast to `Integer.class`, it is successful as instance type does match.

**So the `ClassCastException` is coming because of `Promotion` of literal `1000` to `Integer`.**